# NSubstitute allocates memory in benchmarking

Tags: c#, .net, benchmarking, nsubstitute, benchmarkdotnet

I'm using `NSubstitute` to mock my DB calls for my benchmarking.
For my benchmarking i'm using `BenchmarkDotNet`. Im getting memory allocation although there is no memory allocated in my substituted method.
I need to know what causes this memory allocation and according to what the number of bytes is calculated.

```
    [SimpleJob(RunStrategy.Monitoring, targetCount: 100)]
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    [Orderer(SummaryOrderPolicy.FastestToSlowest)]
    public class PlayerHistory
    {  
        private static ILocalCache _localCache = Substitute.For<ILocalCache>();

        [GlobalSetup]
        public async Task Setup()
        {
            LocalCache.Instance.SetInstance(_localCache);
            Mock(); 
        }

      
        private void Mock()
        {
            LocalCacheController.Instance.GetRealLeagueGroupId("").ReturnsForAnyArgs(BenchmarkConstants.RealLeagueId);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public async Task GetUsersInfoByUsers()
        {
            await TeamManager.Instance.GetPlayerHistory(BenchmarkConstants.RealLeagueId);
        }
    }
```

In my TeamManager:

```
    public async Task<string> GetPlayerHistory(string realLeagueId)
    {
        return LocalCacheController.Instance.GetRealLeagueGroupId(realLeagueId);      
    }
```

This is my benchmark results:

```
|              Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Median | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|-------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|------:|------:|------:|----------:|
| GetUsersInfoByUsers | 63.66 us | 20.96 us | 61.79 us | 29.82 us |     - |     - |     - |     376 B |
```

can you tell me why although i'm substituting the method there is still memory allocated and why how it's calculated?

Comment: NSubstitute is recording the calls made to the mocked members, for later verification. As far as I know you have no way of turning this off so I think you have no other recourse than to either live with the memory allocations, or to not use NSubstitute.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen There is another alternative where I can do benchmarking on a method along with mocking the methods that access the DB?

Comment: Create the mock manually?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know what causes this memory allocation

For that you need to use a Memory Profiler.

> and according to what the number of bytes is calculated.

https://adamsitnik.com/the-new-Memory-Diagnoser/